# React-Native fixed Footer within ScrollView?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I would like to create Views with dynamic content that should have some kind of footer that should normally (if there is enough space) look like they are sticked to the bottom.

Before I introduced ScrollViews my code looked like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
  <View>{content}</View>
  <View>{stickyFooter}</View>
</View>
```

After introducing the ScrollView I had to remove `flex: 1` because otherwise the ScrollView is not scrollable at all. After that `justifyContent` became useless because the height of the flex-container is not set to `100%`. Therefore both `Views` just appear next to each other.

To make clear what my view should look like in general:

[image]

The button should **not** be sticked to the bottom, but it should appear at the bottom (if possible).

Comment: do you mean button should  scroll along with other content, while position should be flex-end?

Comment: The button should not be fixed/static so if the content is too large, the button might be not visible until the user scrolls. What I would like to achieve is a Layout that looks like the button is fixed but actually supports the possibility that the screen size is too small to display the regular content (for example if the device is rotated).

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but for the benefit of those who end up here from a google search like I did, I paste the solution that worked for me below.

Basically, just put the footer outside the scroll view.

*Markup*

```
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View>
         <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            ...
         </ScrollView>
         <TouchableOpacity style={styles.floatingActionButton}>
           <RkButton
             rkType='stretch'>
             <RkText>Do stuff</RkText>
           </RkButton>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

*Styles*

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create(theme => ({
    floatingActionButton: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    left: 10,
    right: 10,
    borderRadius: 10,
  }
}));
```

Comment: but he said that the button should not be sticky, the position absolute actually makes it sticky